# TableVIew и JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, gui, text, tableview

Доброго времени суток.
Имеется TableView с 3 столбцами. Допустим, в первые 2 столбца записывается 200-300 строк, в 3й столбец в этот момент передается null. Наглядно:

```
usersData.add(new dataTable(i+". "+art, tit, null+"\n"));
```

В процессе выполнения программы в арайлист записывается текстовый файл на 5-10к+ строк.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("text.txt")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
        list.add(str+"\n");
```

Собственно эти строки из файла нужно вставить в 3й столбец TableView, но поскольку этот столбец забит null, то все строки из этого файла записываются ниже. Наглядно в интерфейсе программы это выглядит как пустое n-ное кол-во строк в 3м столбце (которые мы сначала заполнили, передавая null в 3й столбик) и вот за этим уже начинаются строки из файла.

Вопрос: как начать записывать эти строки из файла снова в 1ю строку TableView, не перезаписывая 2 остальных столбца?

P.S. Можно ли реализовать горизонтальный скролл текста для каждого столбца отдельно от остальных? или нечто подобное.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример создание таблицы и ее столбцов:

```
            TableView<LobbiItems> tableView;
            TableColumn<LobbiItems, String> tableColumnHost = new TableColumn<>("Хост");
            TableColumn<LobbiItems, String> tableColumnEnemy = new TableColumn<>("Соперник");
            TableColumn<LobbiItems, Circle> tableColumnStatus = new TableColumn<>("Статус");

            tableColumnHost.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
            tableColumnEnemy.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("secondName"));
            tableColumnStatus.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("statusCircle"));

            tableView = new TableView<>();
            tableView.getColumns().addAll(tableColumnHost, tableColumnEnemy, tableColumnStatus);
            tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
```

класс LobbiItems который указывается TableView

```
private StringProperty name;
private StringProperty secondName;
private Circle statusCircle;

public LobbiItems(String name, String secondName,color) {

    this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
    this.secondName = new SimpleStringProperty(secondName);
    this.statusCircle = new Circle(5, 5, 5, color);

}

public void setColor(Color color) {
    statusCircle.setFill(color);
}

public Circle getStatusCircle() {
    return statusCircle;
}

public void setStatusCircle(Circle statusCircle) {
    this.statusCircle = statusCircle;
}

public String getName() {
    return name.get();
}

public StringProperty nameProperty() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name.set(name);
}

public String getSecondName() {
    return secondName.get();
}

public StringProperty secondNameProperty() {
    return secondName;
}

public void setSecondName(String secondName) {
    this.secondName.set(secondName);
}
```

Чтобы добавить или изменить данные:

```
    //изменение
    tableView.getItems().forEach(lobbiItems -> {
    //теперь все элементы таблицы поменяют первую строчку на "Другой текст"
            lobbiItems.setName("Другой текст");
        });
   //добавление
   tableView.getItems.addAll(/*наш элемент LobbiItems*/);
```